# Assert request hasn't happened

Tags: cypress

I have following test

```
it('does not trigger request', () => {
    cy.shortcutThatTriggersRequest()

    cy.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '[url]',
      onRequest: () => {
        cy.contains('request was invoked').should('exist')
      },
    })

    cy.wait(1000)
})
```

which does what I want to do - if given request has happened, it will fail the test and if it didn't then the test will pass.

There're two troublesome things with it though:

- I'm getting `Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.`; I can't omit the `wait` as otherwise the test will be marked as passing (test ends while request is being resolved, test is marked as passing and failure happens afterwards); this happens only when request was made (which makes sense as `route` isn't being triggered, so no `contains` can trigger at the same point as `wait` I guess)
- I'm relying on `cy.contains('request was invoked').should('exist')` to mark the test as failing. I don't want to do that; while no such string will ever exist, it's a workaround; ideally I'd want to co `cy.fail()` but I don't see such method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to achieve this, I've used following:

```
it.skip('does not trigger products requests', () => {
    Cypress.on('fail', (error, runnable) => {
      if (error.message.indexOf('Timed out retrying') !== 0) throw error
    })

    cy.server()
    cy.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '[url]',
    }).as('products')

    cy.shortcutThatTriggersRequest()
    cy.wait('@products', {
      requestTimeout: 1000,
    }).then((xhr) => {
      assert.isNull(xhr.response.body)
    })
})
```

If a timeout is reached, it will be handled within `fail` and thus test will pass. If it gets inside `then` then the test will fail.

There's an additional issue here, that if multiple routes are checked (`cy.wait['route1', 'route2']`) and one of them doesn't exist, then the test will pass even though one of the assertions specifies that it shouldn't, for example:

```
it.skip('does not trigger products requests', () => {
    Cypress.on('fail', (error, runnable) => {
      if (error.message.indexOf('Timed out retrying') !== 0) throw error
    })

    cy.server()
    cy.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '[url]',
    }).as('route1')

    cy.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '[url]',
    }).as('route2')

    cy.shortcutThatTriggersRequest()
    cy.wait(['@route1', '@route2'], {
      requestTimeout: 1000,
    }).then((xhrs) => {
      assert.isNull(xhrs[0].response.body)
      assert.isNull(xhrs[1].response.body)
    })
})
```

passes even though there was a request to one of those endpoints (I assume it's a bug caused by handling of `onfail`. What needs to be done, is the request assertions need to be sequential:

```
cy.wait('@route1', {
  requestTimeout: 1000,
}).then((xhr) => {
  assert.isNull(xhr.response.body)
})

cy.wait('@route2', {
  requestTimeout: 1000,
}).then((xhr) => {
  assert.isNull(xhr.response.body)
})
```

As far as I can see we can't check the type of `error` in `onfail` as it's always `CypressError` irregardless of what caused it

Answer (score 0):

I have used following setup with module variable.
`cy.wrap` failed inside `cy.intercept`. Maybe `Cypress.env` could be used but I guess it would leak to another test.

```
let requestPerformed;

beforeEach(() => {
   requestPerformed = false;
});

it('', () => {
  cy.intercept('/route', () => {
    requestPerformed = true;
  });

  cy.someTrigger();

  cy.wrap(requestPerformed).should('be.false');
});
```

I believe it could be generalized to a command.